# Ruby on Rails: how to writer seed data for a table with two (multiple) foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

I have four tables:

```
Honors (student_id,course_id,prof_id)#referencing 3 tables
student(student_id, name,phnumber,)
course(course_id, cousename)
Prof_id(prof_id,prfEmail)
```

In honor.db

```
class Honor < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :course
      belongs_to :student
      belongs_to :professor
end
```

In course.db

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :honors
end
```

Similarly with student.rb, professor.rb

can you please help me with writing the seed data for this tables.

For writing single foreign key reference I know how to write. but i am not sure how to do it for 3 foreign references on a single table.

Example for single foreign key(a person has many reviews) :

```
Person.create(first_name: 'Nicol',last_name: 'Cagase',dob: Date.new(1964,1,7),

            reviews: Review.create([
                {stars: 4 , title: 'The Game of Thrones', commentary: 'waiting for next episode'},
                {stars: 3 , title: 'KingsMan', commentary: 'average'},
    ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

honor = Honors.create() will create your first seed

honor.student.create() will create the student and the relationship

honor.course.create() same as student, repeat for professor